# Why it is not possible to have questions sorted ascending by views?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Shouldn't there be a feature to sort by ascending views be there?
There are many questions which do not have much views and go unnoticed.

If so, why not?

Comment: You could search for [low views...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+views%3A..20+answers%3A0)

Comment: You can also look at the [Tumbleweed badge page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed).

Comment: Why is it not possible? Because no one programmed it to be sortable by views. It wasn't a requirement, so they didn't develop it. Also, no one's asked for it... until now. :)